# Has anyone created a method for cloning a squarespace site to create a new squarespace site?

Tags: duplicates, clone, squarespace, weebly

As I understand it, Squarespace provides no method to clone a site. Clone means to create a new squarespace site (not re-create ex-squarespace).

My latest project includes creating a 'base site' and then cloning it for different customers (and each clone will have it's own template tweaks, new blogs and calendar, etc), but all the rest of the content will be the same as the original.

I'm figuring that some enterprising developer/firm has solved this problem using scripts, etc.  Please help! Or I will need to use Weebly instead, which DOES support cloning sites.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. Here's a [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091859/squarespace-transfer-one-page-to-another-website), and an [official answer from Squarespace](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205809768-Can-I-duplicate-a-Squarespace-site-).

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with a Squarespace rep...  He explained that it is possible if you follow these steps:

1.)  Select the website from your Dashboard that you want to DUPLICATE.
2.)  Click on the 3 dots and choose "DUPLICATE WEBSITE."
3.)  You will need to invite the future recipient of the new website to be a "Contributor."
4.)  Then you may Transfer Ownership to that "Contributor."

Contact Squarespace and describe the above steps and they will help you through it.