# Squarespace transfer one page to another website

Tags: squarespace

I need to transfer a single page over to another Squarespace website. My client wanted a whole website done but due to budget issues is now only getting a single page for the time being. If it matters, I was building the page on my own account, with the intention of transferring ownership to him once complete.

Is there an easy way to transfer just one single index? Its several "pages" worth of content that is to be used as a landing page.

I can just do it manually, but if there is a better solution I'd much rather go that route.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "building the page on my own account". I've been doing this exact scenario for years now and have picked numerous methods of handling it that sometimes don't even involved transferring the page.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, Squarespace does not support such a duplication or transfer of content from one Squarespace site to another, despite offering [a limited data export feature](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206566687-Exporting-your-site).

There are two options that you may attempt, both a little rough, and neither guaranteed to work:

**1)** You may attempt to export for Wordpress, then import from Wordpress using the XML file you exported.

- Settings > Advanced > Import/Export > Export > Wordpress > Download
- Settings > Advanced > Import/Export > Import > Wordpress > Advanced > XML Export Upload (add exported file)
- Then reassemble the pages into a parent/child relationship, add missing settings and images, etc. There will most certainly be errors and missing data from the import.

**2)** A developer (not associated with Squarespace) has developed a plugin (not free) that does allow the duplication of pages between sites. It is a third-party solution, not supported by Squarespace.

- [Squarespace Importer](http://www.squarespacewebsites.com/products/squarespace-site-importer)
- [Video on using the Squarespace Importer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T5AcxFRbKE)

Note that, using this tool, it is my understanding that you would not be able to duplicate the index page/folder and its sub-pages in a single action. Instead, you'd have to create the index page/folder in the new site, then individually duplicate each child page within it. Once all child pages were duplicated, you could then move them within the manually recreated index page/folder.

You may also consider [submitting a feature request to the Squarespace Customer Care team](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).